# Multi-layered ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I'm currently working on a project in which I need something like the following:

```
- MainGroup 1 (Expandable)
  - SubGroup 1 (Expandable)
    - SubSubGroup 1 (Expandable)
      - Child View
      - Child View
      - ...
    - SubSubGroup 2 (Expandable)
      - Child View
      - Child View
      - ...
  - SubGroup 2 (Expandable)
    - SubSubGroup 3 (Expandable)
      - Child View
      - ...
    - SubSubGroup 4 (Expandable)
      - Child View
      - ...
  - SubGroup 3 (Expandable)
    - Child View
    - ...
- MainGroup 2 (Expandable)
  - ...
```

At most it would be an `ExpandableListView` inside an `ExpandableListView` inside an `ExpandableListView` - so 3 layers of `ExpandableListView`:

- `MainGroup` would only hold other `ExpandableListView`.
- `SubGroup` would hold other `ExpandableListView` except for the last two, which will allways just be `ChildViews`. (I'm thinking those two could just be substituted with the one for `SubSubGroup`)
- `SubSubGroup` would allways hold `ChildViews`.

My problem is that I think I fail to understand the basic principles of how the `ExpandableListView` layouts it's children. I've looked at examples like [this](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2011/02/3-level-expandable-lists.html), but can't get my head around the functionality.

I've tried simply adding an `ExpandableListView` as a child in another - but something doesn't work as only the first item of the inner `ExpandableListView` is visible if you expand one of the outer groups. I can however by setting the height of the outer groups container manually make it big enough to show all items in the inner `ExpandableListView`. To be optimal, calculation of height should of course be done on the fly.

So, to get to some more solid questions:

- Can someone give me an explanation of the `ExpandableListView` "lifecycle" (by this I mean instantation, re-use of views, expand/collapse listeners) including:

  - How and when is an `ExpandableListView` notified that a child is expanded/collapsed?
  - How does the `ExpandableListView` know how much space to make for all children to fit into a group container?
- How much benefit is there in using the `ExpandableListView` to create the above, compared to just mixing together my own solution using some `LinearLayouts` and some `OnClickListeners`?

---

**Edit**

For my last question I might note that there can be anywhere from 1 to 20+ `MainGroups`.

Comment: your solution has been solved..?

Comment: I never actually solved the problem as I was moved to another project, but QuickNick's answer would definitely have been the way to go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, let me recommend you [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/ExpandableListView.java?av=f) site. It has sources of Android SDK classes. Thanks for them, I've found out base principles of AdapterViews (I gave you a link to ExpandableListView, but it's better if you research not only it, but its class-parents as well).

Now, your questions and my answers:

> How and when is an ExpandableListView notified that a child is
>   expanded/collapsed?

See method [handleItemClick(View v, int position, long id)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/ExpandableListView.java#548)

> How does the ExpandableListView know how much space to make for all
>   children to fit into a group container?

I didn't research this question well, but as far as I know, it's made by the method requestLayout(). Also we found out that one scrollable View cannot be embedded into another scrollable View. (It's wide-known mistake: to put ListView into ScrollView or ListView into ExpandableListView).

> How much benefit is there in using the ExpandableListView to create
>   the above, compared to just mixing together my own solution using some
>   LinearLayouts and some OnClickListeners?

AdapterViews are faster. But your construction is too complex even for ExpandableListView. You may use 2 solutions.

1. Guru-solution: if you're professional of designing your own
   Views/ViewGroups from the scratch (I mean, you understand methods
   requestLayout(), dispatchDraw() and so on), then write your own
   GrandExpandableListAdapter with 3 levels.
2. Medium-solution: use ExpandableListAdapter for first 2 levels and use LinearLayouts for
   3rd level.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [this](http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/) project out. I haven't tried it, but I guess it's worth a try. The default ExpanadableListView is quite limited, designed originally to support only 2 levels. You can hack around with it to get it to support more levels than that, but it'll get messy.

Comment: How would using it effect my licensing? I'm developing for a company, so I can't really do stuff that would demand my source code to be open source.

Comment: I'm not avare that the BSD license demands you to keep your project open sourced. At least I couldn't find anything that states otherwise here: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php . I may be terribly wrong though.

Comment: Licensing aside - it would fulfill my purpose so +1. I do find that just running the simple example provided in the source is quite laggy, so I'm still looking for answers to my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is not the complete solution still its a 3 layered Expandable List. So its left to you how you style it.

here is the class

```
package com.custom.nagee;

import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class CustomemExpandible extends ExpandableListActivity{
    LayoutInflater inflator;
    boolean flag = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        inflator = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        if(flag){
            v.findViewById(childPosition).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            flag = false;
            return true;
        }
        v.findViewById(childPosition).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        flag = true;
        return true;
    }
    class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)inflator.inflate(R.layout.group, null);
            linearLayout.getChildAt(1).setId(childPosition);
            return linearLayout;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return ((LinearLayout)inflator.inflate(R.layout.group, null));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

and here goes the xml file

**group.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/back"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dip" 
    android:text="DONE" >
</TextView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dip" 
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="DONE">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DONE" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DONE" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is under color folder for changing text color, its left you , you can even change the background for getting better looks.

**back.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#808080"/>
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:color="#808080"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#808080"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#000000"/>
    <item android:color="#FF0000"/> <!-- not selected -->
</selector>
```

hope it works...