# ExpandablelistView making a parent of the groups of the childrens

Tags: java, android, arraylist, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am a newbie in android , I want  to create an expandablelistview with childs of action event.

I have  followed the steps on this link to accomplish my goal.

http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-expandablelistview-example.html

The project worked fine for me.

But I want to make   few changes on it.

I want to make a parents for the parent  of the childs (not only parents and childs) in other words

grandfather.

for example .

if fruits is a parent of apple,Mango,Banana, and orange I want to include fruits itself in a parent called foods.

To do that I change MyExpandableAdapter class code as following:-

```
    public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter 

    {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Object> childtems,parentofparents;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<String> parentItems, child,pair;

    // constructor
    public MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents, ArrayList<Object> childern ,ArrayList<Object>  parent)
    {
        this.parentofparents =parent;
        this.parentItems = parents;
        this.childtems = childern;
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity) 
    {
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    // method getChildView is called automatically for each child view.
    //  Implement this method as per your requirement
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        child = (ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition);
        pair = (ArrayList<String>) parentofparents.get(groupPosition);
        TextView textView = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, null);
        }

         // get the textView reference and set the value
        textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChild);
        textView.setText(child.get(childPosition));

        // set the ClickListener to handle the click event on child item
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, child.get(childPosition),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    // method getGroupView is called automatically for each parent item
    // Implement this method as per your requirement
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_view, null);
        }

        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(pair.get(groupPosition));
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) 
    {
        return ((ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() 
    {
        return parentItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) 
    {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition)
    {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() 
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

And I changed ExpandableListMainActivity class to the following code:-

```
public class ExpandableListMainActivity extends ExpandableListActivity
{
    // Create ArrayList to hold parent Items and Child Items
    private ArrayList<String> parentItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Object> childItems = new ArrayList<Object>();
    private ArrayList<Object> ParentOfparent = new ArrayList<Object>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        // Create Expandable List and set it's properties
        ExpandableListView expandableList = getExpandableListView(); 
        expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
        expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
        expandableList.setClickable(true);

        // Set the Items of Parent
        setGroupParents();
        // Set The Child Data
        setChildData();

        // Create the Adapter
        MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(parentItems, childItems,ParentOfparent);

        adapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);

        // Set the Adapter to expandableList
        expandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
        expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(this);
    }

    // method to add parent Items
    public void setGroupParents() 
    {
        parentItems.add("Fruits");
        parentItems.add("Flowers");
        parentItems.add("Animals");
        parentItems.add("Birds");
        ParentOfparent .add(parentItems);
    }

    // method to set child data of each parent
    public void setChildData() 
    {

        // Add Child Items for Fruits
        ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Apple");
        child.add("Mango");
        child.add("Banana");
        child.add("Orange");

        childItems.add(child);

        // Add Child Items for Flowers
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Rose");
        child.add("Lotus");
        child.add("Jasmine");
        child.add("Lily");

        childItems.add(child);

        // Add Child Items for Animals
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Lion");
        child.add("Tiger");
        child.add("Horse");
        child.add("Elephant");

        childItems.add(child);

        // Add Child Items for Birds
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Parrot");
        child.add("Sparrow");
        child.add("Peacock");
        child.add("Pigeon");

        childItems.add(child);
    }



}
```

But I get an error on the line

MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(parentItems, childItems,ParentOfparent);

The constructor MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList, ArrayList) is undefined.

Can someone guides me.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8293538/2345913)

Answer (score 0):

ParentOfParents should start with a lower case letter, else java will think its a class

so:

```
private ArrayList<Object> ParentOfparent = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

should be

```
private ArrayList<Object> parentOfParent = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Comment: only just realized how old this question is.... hope the answer is still useful to someone :P